# Why SOCI regression tests for PostgreSQL fail on Windows?

Tags: c++, postgresql, soci

I build and test SOCI 3.2 on Windows 10 with Visual Studio 2015, using this batch:

```
SET PREFIX=..\soci-3.2.3-install
SET POSTGRES_DIR=E:\PostgreSQL\9.5

cmake^
 -G "NMake Makefiles"^
 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release^
 -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=%PREFIX%^
 -DSOCI_TESTS=ON^
 -DWITH_ODBC=OFF^
 -DWITH_POSTGRESQL=ON^
 -DPOSTGRESQL_INCLUDE_DIR="%POSTGRES_DIR%\include"^
 -DPOSTGRESQL_LIBRARIES="%POSTGRES_DIR%\lib\libpq.lib"^
 -DSOCI_POSTGRESQL_TEST_CONNSTR="host=localhost port=5432 dbname=postgres user=eagui"^
 ..\soci-3.2.3

nmake
nmake test
```

I also comment line 27 in `soci-3.2.3\core\soci-platform.h` before build, in order to avoid a macro redefinition error caused by one the VC headers. I make sure `E:\PostgreSQL\9.5\bin` is added to `PATH`. The command prompt has admin privileges.

After running the batch, I get the following output from the test:

```
...
3/4 Test #3: soci_postgresql_test .............***Failed    1.37 sec
    Start 4: soci_postgresql_test_static
4/4 Test #4: soci_postgresql_test_static ......***Failed    0.17 sec

50% tests passed, 2 tests failed out of 4

Total Test time (real) =   1.63 sec

The following tests FAILED:
          3 - soci_postgresql_test (Failed)
          4 - soci_postgresql_test_static (Failed)
Errors while running CTest
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'echo' : return code '0x8'
Stop.
```

I have configured the PostgreSQL server to accept trust connections. The `postgres` database and `eagui` user exist in the server.

Any idea why tests do not pass for PostgreSQL and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**At least one of the schemas set in the user's search path must exist in the database.**

By default, the search path is set to look for a schema named after the user. This of course can be changed, so in order to see which schemas are looked for, the `SHOW search_path;` command can be run. For any new user that is created, the search path is set by default to `"$user", public`.

In this case the user `eagui` was specified in the connection string, but no `eagui` or `public` schema did exist in the `postgres` database. Creating one of these schemas make the tests pass.